# Material2 Icons and Title Text CSS Not Aligning Properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material2

I am running into a styling issue while using material2 icons in my Angular app. Specifically, I have a button displaying both a material2 icon and some text - next to each other, running left to right. Right now the icons are aligning in the center of the button, but the text of the button is aligning below that icon, so as not to be centered on the button.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="wizard-container">
  <div class="intake-step-item">
    <span><i class="material-icons md-28">face</i></span><span class="intake-step-title">General</span>
  </div>
  <div class="intake-step-item">
    <span><i class="material-icons md-28">perm_contact_calendar</i></span><span class="intake-step-title">Availability</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the relevant css:

```
#wizard-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -10;
}

.intake-step-item {
    background: #d7d7d7;
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.intake-step-item > .active {
  background: #46AB61;
}

.intake-step-title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.material-icons.md-28 { 
  font-size: 28px; 
  padding: 4px; }
```

I tried using negative margin and negative padding on the title text, but that didn't make any difference. What do I need to do to get the title text of each button to align in the center of the button?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. Can you post a working demo?

Comment: You're saying nothing looks wrong with my css?

Comment: I'm saying it's hard to tell because I can't reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: I've checked and it's doing the same thing in both Chrome and FF - where the icon is centered but the text is dropping below that.

Comment: This is what you've provided: https://jsfiddle.net/798hdxvg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
#wizard-container .intake-step-item {
  display: flex;
}
```

Working example:

```css
#wizard-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -10;
}

.intake-step-item {
    background: #d7d7d7;
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
}

.intake-step-item > .active {
  background: #46AB61;
}

.intake-step-title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.material-icons.md-28 { 
  font-size: 28px; 
  padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



<div id="wizard-container">
  <div class="intake-step-item">
    <span><i class="material-icons md-28">face</i></span><span class="intake-step-title">General</span>
  </div>
  <div class="intake-step-item">
    <span><i class="material-icons md-28">perm_contact_calendar</i></span><span class="intake-step-title">Availability</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it feels like your CSS somewhat conflicts with [`Material Design guidelines`](https://material.io/guidelines/).

**Note:** Don't forget to [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) before you deploy to production.

Comment: That works. Thanks! And re: material design guidelines, are you referring to the size of font I'm using for the icons?

Comment: If you need to translate it to technical specs, yes, but not only. Material is usability, it's fluid motion, should feel alive, should feel natural should feel like it's responding to user actions in a fluid and natural way. Above all, MD should be very easy and intuitive to use. That's why the buttons have certain sizes, so they are still usable on all devices. I linked the guidelines as they have said it there, with examples, much better than I could say it in a comment here.

Comment: I have changed it so I'm using one of the designated sizes: 24px. And I'm now not applying any padding to the icon in addition. Looks to be working well. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck and happy coding!